# Recursive function to convert from decimal to binary

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, binary

My code has a  problem with conversion of the number 3

I would like to write a function which converts a decimal number into a binary one. The principle of recursion must be used. I have already written the following code.

```
    Function recursive(number As Integer) As String

        Dim result As String

        If number > 0 Then

            Dim binaryNumber As String
            Dim digit As Integer

            binaryNumber = recursive(number / 2)
            digit = number Mod 2
            result = result & binaryNumber & digit

        End If

        recursive = result

    End Function
```

**Right result:**

- Input: 10

  - Output: 1010

**Wrong result:**

- Input: 3

  - Output: 101

It also works reasonably well, but I get a wrong result when I try to convert the decimal number 3. Where is the error?

Comment: Unfortunately not helpful. I have to write my own function, which is recursive - that's the requirements.

Comment: It will fail for 3, 7, 11, etc. You write "I have to write my own function, which is recursive - that's the requirements". Is this a homework problem?

Comment: `number / 2 ` will make it floating if `number` is odd. Try to use `number \ 2` for integer division by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function recursive(number As Integer) As String

        Dim result As String

        If number > 0 Then

            Dim binaryNumber As String
            Dim digit As Integer
            digit = number Mod 2
            number = Int(number / 2)
            binaryNumber = recursive(number)
            result = result & binaryNumber & digit

        End If

        recursive = result
End Function
```